# solution of a coupled differential equation with variable

Tags: differential-equations

I have written a code of a set of a differential equation and for one of the variables in the differential equation I have written set of another differential equation how should I call it in the first set of differential equation in Mathematica.

Comment: These are four coupled diffrential equations ds1/dt= -i[a x(t) s1 + c x(t) s2],ds2/dt=-i[c x(t) s1 +(d-e x(t)) s2 - f s3],ds3/dt=-i[-f s2+(e x(t)-d) s3 + c x(t) s4], ds4/dt =-i[ c x(t) s3 + (b-a x(t)) s4] and x(t) we will get from solving second order diffrential equation m d^2x/dt^2+w^2 m x+ 3 A x^2+ 4 B x^3= e V cos(wt)

Comment: if numericall possible then also it will helpfull for me.

Comment: It would be helpful to put your formatted code in your question? The more code you show from what you have attempted the more chance people have of being able to answer you

Comment: Just include all ODEs in one NDSolve call.